# Whenever user adds a <li>, jquery chooses a specific colour from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, colors

I'm new to javascript, so be easy.

I just want to the user to be able to write `<li> </li>` and jquery will choose the colour depending on the list order. At the moment, the user would have to put in `class="b"`, or `class="c"`.

Am I right in assuming I would create an array of colours, and use some sort of loop?

A visual example of what I'm hoping to achieve: http://popmeup.org/about

Comment: You are on the right way :) Don't loop whole array, just select random color.

Comment: Could you elaborate in any way? :)

Comment: Sure, but only after lunch :)

Comment: Do you still need a solution or you are happy with @Simon's answer?

Comment: His answer is perfect, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Unless you have a hell of a lot of colors, using CSS nth-child is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXXLZ/1/)?

```
var colors = [ 'BlueViolet', 'CadetBlue', 'Coral', 'Crimson', 'DarkGoldenRod', 'DarkOliveGreen'],
    li = document.getElementById('colorthis').getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var elem = li[i],
        color = colors[0];
    elem.style.color = color;
    colors.push(color);
    colors.shift();
}
```

You just define a list of colors and the loop styles each list element. Once used, a color gets appended to the color list, so you can style unlimited amounts of elements with a limited list of colors.

Comment: That looks brilliant. Could I ask, what is the purpose of .push and .shift?

Comment: This is just a routine to move the first array element to the end of that array. `.push` appends the first color to the array (colors[0]) and shift removes the now duplicate first element. Next time colors[0] will be another color.

Comment: You're very clever. My last quandary — how to target <li> within a certain div?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) selector to specify the order of the colours:

```
li:nth-child(2n - 1) {
    color: red;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
    color: blue;
}
```

The above basic example would colour alternating `<li>` elements in red and blue, starting with red. Take a look at [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PkjPN/).

Comment: That sounds good. What if the list is infinite, is there a way of making the colours start over, after 50 list items?

Comment: `li:nth-child(n+50)` would to that. You can take a look at more examples at: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: But would that not make all list items over 50 just one colour? Rather than starting the order again.

Comment: @TomJulianHume There probably would be, you'd just have to get the indexes passed to `:nth-child` correct to set that up. This isn't something I have a lot of experience doing though.

Comment: You can get a CSS preprocessor to generate the nth-child selectors for you:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/yoCDG (you can see the compiled results by clicking the "SCSS" text above the middle window).

Answer (score -1):

you want like this:

```
$(".item").click(function() {  
  if ($(this).hasclass("A")) {
    coorColor = "blue";
  } else if ($(this).hasclass("B") {
    coorColor = "red";
  }

  $("body").css("background", coorColor);
});
```

Comment: Why on click? He didn't say anything about clicking. It should be on loading.

Answer (score -1):

**With CSS:**

```
li.a{
    color:#000000;
}

li.b{
    color:#ff00ff;
}
```

Working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/VJJnD/1/

**Width jQuery:**

```
$('li.a').css('color', '#000000');
$('li.b').css('color', '#ff00ff');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VJJnD/